# Jquery and Socket.io conflict

Tags: jquery, socket.io, conflict, impactjs

I'm trying to use ImpactJS, a JS framework.
I want to add socket.io functions.
As soon as I add socket.io there is an error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: sock is not defined jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4
```

My class where I use soket.io :[here](http://pastebin.com/2QrxFSCr) (end of the file)

My index.html : [here](http://pastebin.com/TFpjnUsn)

I don't understand why I can't use both.
Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem.
Socket is loaded in index.html and not in Player.js.

Map editor can't load socket.
To solve this problem in Player.js :

```
if (typeof sock != 'undefined')
sock.emit('update', this.padmap, this.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Index line 35

```
var sock = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
```

Class line 134

```
sock.emit('update', this.padmap, this.id);
```

sock is not in the window scope so this will not work. Change `var sock` to `window.sock` and `sock.emit` to `window.sock.emit`.

However using global variables are frowned upon. If you're using global variables you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I understant but after changes I have other error messages :  
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . localhost/:35
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined Player.js:52  
My new files :  
Player.js : [link](http://pastebin.com/UMkakdKW)  
index.html : [link](http://pastebin.com/uDCrbvhM)

Comment: window.sock isn't defined. figure out why window.sock isn't defined. Also don't use window like I said. You should not use global variables.